# how to use if in a select statement

Tags: select, if-statement, case, sql

my goal is to the following:

**select name, address, day,hoursworked
{
if hoursworked>8 then (hoursworked -8) as OT 
else ''
}
from testtable**

how can i accomplish that. i have tried to use case, but i keep getting error regarding can't convert varchar to an INT. i need that in a select statement.

Comment: Is hoursworked stored as varchar or int in your table?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're establishing the type of the column with hoursworked-8, i.e. the column should be an int, but then you're also selecting '', which is varchar. Use NULL or 0 instead.

```
SELECT name, address, day, CASE WHEN hoursworked > 8 THEN hoursworked-8 ELSE NULL END AS overtime
```

Comment: I believe i had tried that one but the problem was that hoursworked is a decimal. i.e 8.52 hours and by doing just that, and it rounds that number to an INT and it the data gets incorrect because the OT isn't accurate then.